# Run jQuery modal dialog if PHP returns 0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I need to run [jQuery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) if `mainOptim.php` returns 0. Now Firebug says `$dialog is not defined`. What should I change in the code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .html('This dialog will show every time!')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Basic Dialog'
            });
    });
    function click_function_ps() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'callpage.php?page=optim/mainOptim.php',
            data: 'earl='+$('#earl').val(),
            success: function(html,msg){
                if(msg === '1'){
                    $('#opt_container').html(html);
                } else {
                    $dialog.dialog('open');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="fragment-2">
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%"> 
                <form name="optform" method="post" action="#">
                    <div class = "boxx">
                        <label for="earl"><span>Parameter:</span></label>
                        <input type="text" class="input-text" value="5" size="11" maxlength="11" name="earl" id="earl">
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <a href="#" class="regular" onclick="click_function_ps();">
                            <img src="images/opt.png" alt=""/> Run 
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you declared it as a local variable using the var keyword in the *ready* scope.
Remove the `var` in front of the declaration (`var $dialog`).